# jQuery file download plugin , is got file

Tags: jquery, download

im using jQuery FileDownload plugin which can be found [here](http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/)

everything works fine, only thing i cannot find is how to know if a file has been downloaded.

now this is important so you wont write unrelated answers.

Server sometimes returns `null` when he couldn't generate the file.

how can i know if the `ContentFileResult` is `null` or with `File` when i get the response?

`.failcallback` only works when the entire communication fails, its not the case.

`.successcallback` works when the entire communication succeeds, not necessary that a file has downloaded nad the received parameter is the url itself.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. he no one will upvote and show he needs this answer, i will delete it in 2 days because only i needed it.

Instead of return `ContentFileResult` i return `ActionResult`.
When i have an error or some reason to to return a file, i return

```
new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed);
```